# Can post-doc inquiries be parallel?

Tags: career-path, postdocs

I am a Computer Science PhD student in the US about to graduate this year and want to contact a few professors; say, A and B; in my field to know if they have a post-doc position available.

Should I wait until A replies before sending out inquiry to B?

My concern is that if I ask A and B at the same time and end up securing a post-doc with A, and B later says yes he has an open position, will B regard me as unprofessional since the inquiry is a waste of time for both him and me? If yes, I have to send out inquiries sequentially, which greatly reduces the efficiency of the hunt process.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16063/what-is-the-best-way-to-turn-down-a-postdoc-offer (at least it showed the practice of multiple inquiries is not a rarity)

Answer (score 4):

You should apply all at once. Everyone else will be, and professors and labs know that you will apply to multiple jobs at the same time. Once you *accept* a postdoc somewhere, you should immediately withdraw your other applications that are still pending. You may find yourself needing to get an extension of time from one organization that has made you an offer while you wait on your pending offers. Hopefully, you will be able have several offers to consider at once in order to make the best choice, but you may have to decline an offer if better ones are probably coming down the line and an extension of time isn't available.