# Can I refuse a grant position I was offered and still hope to work there in future?

Tags: etiquette, funding

After an interview, I was offered a pre-doc grant for one year. Although I'm very interested in the research, I have other reasons to prefer staying in my current position: I think it would be easier for me to pursue the PhD I want from here.
Is it possible to kindly refuse the proposal and still hope to work with that group in the future, or would I burn bridges this way? If it is possible, how can I refuse the proposal without offending anyone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to turn down a Postdoc offer?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16063/what-is-the-best-way-to-turn-down-a-postdoc-offer)

Comment: it would be a pre-doc position actually, so I believe I'm in a different situation (or at least I fell so), because I have just a little experience

Comment: What is a pre-doc? It is not standard terminology in my field.

Comment: it means I have a master degree, but I still don't have a PhD, neverthless I'm working in research. Is not usual in my field neither...

Comment: If you train elsewhere, and become a start, then apply as a post doc or faculty member, then the department gets you and doesn't have to pay to train you.  Be polite about turning down the position, but I don't believe you're burning bridges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Professionally, they should understand, if explained to them in a polite and respectful way. After all it is your life, and they need to respect your decision. Yes, it is disappointing, but it should not burn bridges - good people are not easy to find and they should be happy to keep in touch; who knows what the future brings.

However, if they were so disappointed that they would be indeed offended by your decision, then it is likely that there are other problems lying in wait for you at that group, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I assume this is for the UK because of your profile and the fact that you call it a "grant." I don't know how it works in the UK and much less the specific dynamics of your case, but I can tell you that in the US people turn down offers all the time based on their interests at heart, and although it's of course disappointing we acknowledge people's desire to pursue their own happiness (hey, it's in the Declaration of Independence).